# "Failed to find mounted volume for"

Tags: android

I'm downloading files from a third party server.

I have a lot of testing devices and sometimes one won't be able to download and show the following error :

```
Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/app/files/Download/
Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/app/files/Download/tmp/TheGenius/
```

And this goes for the hundreth of files I'm trying to download.

From there on, rebooting nor reinstalling the app won't help.

Any idea of what could go wrong (I've found very few resources on this issue on the googling machine)

Answer (score 0):

Tried cleaning "Data" (and maybe Cache) from the App? 
(Applications -> Find the app -> Clean Data/Cache)

I have a similar issue and cleaning the Data works.
Not sure what's causing that though.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar with android studio attempting to run an app with an emulated device, switching to a new device fixed the issue, so it is possible that the issue is with the device and not the program.